# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources" when using eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I am developing a J2EE application using Eclipse...and in that application..i used a jquery Plugin "DataTable 1.9.4" to create a table grid with all its functionality.

But in javascript file of DataTable plugin..an error occured like below :

```
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodBinding cannot be cast to org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LocalVariableBinding
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.localVariableBinding(SingleNameReference.java:226)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.checkNPE(Expression.java:320)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:67)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.analyseAssignment(SingleNameReference.java:84)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.analyseCode(Assignment.java:63)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:110)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpression.java:74)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldReference.analyseAssignment(FieldReference.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.analyseCode(Assignment.java:63)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:110)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpression.java:74)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.analyseCode(LocalDeclaration.java:73)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:110)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpression.java:74)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:86)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:110)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpression.java:74)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.analyseCode(Expression.java:184)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:65)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.analyseCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:155)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:609)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:355)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:288)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:86)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:227)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:58)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:291)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

To resolve this error i explored about it..and below are links which i explored :

[Bug 391880 - javascript validator throws error, unable to build project](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391880)

[ClassCastException](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse/issues/52)

but still i didn't get any proper solution to resolve this error....
So please guide me to remove this error...its very urgent for me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=415822 No fix or workaround mentioned.

Comment: Dear @greg-449, I know this an eclipse error...but is there any way to remove it....please help me to resolve it.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score -2):

I resolved the issue by replacing the file *jQuery.datatables.js* with latest *jQuery.datatables.min.js* that i got from datatables.net.

Comment: "now I dont have the" ... ?! Something is missing I guess :)